# Preventing brute force attacks against ssh - on Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, ssh, brute-force-attacks

Same question as this [Preventing brute force attacks against ssh?](https://serverfault.com/questions/4188/preventing-brute-force-attacks-against-ssh) - specifically for Windows Server.  Strong passwords, RSA auth, and port knocking all apply to windows - but I'm hoping for something to block repeatedly failing IP addresses.

I'm not attached to any particular SSH server, would be nice if there was a server with something built in.  Googling reveals a lot of brute force *clients* for Windows, but nothing for servers getting attacked.

Answer (score 1):

[DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sf.net/) is a python script; it may be able to be made to work on Windows.

Failing that, [this](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/12081) guy apparently wrote a knockoff of it in Visual Basic(!!).

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [Cygwin SSHd Autoblock Failed Logins](https://serverfault.com/questions/43360/cygwin-sshd-autoblock-failed-logins/43900)
That does not have lots of capacity like fail2ban does, but I think it is something you were looking for.