# Connecting to a port-knocking protected resource

Tags: security, ssh, bash

Considering the excellent answers on the SF question "[Preventing brute force attacks against SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/4188/preventing-brute-force-attacks-against-ssh?rq=1)", I am considering configuring port knocking on a test server. I am debating how I will connect to this server and to other port-knocking servers easily.

I usually configure rsa authentication, addresses, and user names in `/.ssh/config` as such:

```
Host msUpdate
    User bgates
    Hostname updates.microsoft.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.bgates.pub
```

Thus, I can simply type `ssh msUpdate` to log into the server. So far as I know `/.ssh/config` has no facility for configuring port knocking. Thus, I am considering a wrapper script for `ssh` that will automatically handle knocking:

```
$ cat login
#!/bin/bash

msUpdate=( 2000 3000 4000 )
otherServer=( 1024 2048 4096 )

for PORT in ${$@}; do
    ssh -p $PORT
    sleep 1
done

ssh $@
```

My question is how to write the `for` line. I cannot seem to get the script to recognise the argument as the name of an array to substitute. Although ostensibly a Bash question, I ask on SF because I feel that the completed script will be most useful to users of this site, and also because if there is a better way than it will most likely be here that someone will let me know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use [indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006), but an associative array (AKA "hash") is the better approach. You will need to use a language that supports this feature such as Bash 4, AWK, ksh93, Perl, Python, etc.

If you have Bash 4, you can use associative arrays as follows. The values can't be arrays, but you can use space-separated lists of ports since the list members won't include spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A servers
servers[msUpdate]='2000 3000 4000'
servers[otherServer]='1024 2048 4096'

for port in ${servers[$1]}
do
    ssh -p "$port" "$1"
    sleep 1
done

ssh "$1"
```

Call the script with the name of the server you want to log in to:

```
./scriptname otherServer
```

Use something other than "login" for your script name since that's the name of an existing executable.

Always avoid using all-caps variable names to prevent possible name collision with shell variables.

Comment: Thanks. Bash 4 seems to be available on the machine from which I would use this script. I had considered Python but I do prefer Bash for scripts whose main purpose is to run shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the array name in your for loop

```
for PORT in "${msUpdate[@]}"
do
    ssh -p $PORT host.tld
done
```

Better is subjective, I've seen port knocking implemented with a script like this but it used nmap to do the knocking not ssh

```
for PORT in "${msUpdate[@]}"
do
   nmap -Pn --host_timeout 100 --max-retries 0 -p $PORT host.tld
done
ssh -p someport host.tld
```

You may also want to consider an alternative like [Duo Security](https://www.duosecurity.com/)'s two factor authentication.

Comment: The idea is that I want to be able to use the script for different hosts, which might need different knock patterns. That is why I mention the name of the server in the arguments, and why there are multiple arrays.

Comment: @dotancohen rather than do it for you I chose to show you how to use the variables so you could learn and then extend that knowledge to help yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I certainly don't want someone to do the work for me. I don't learn that way! But I don't see where you've addressed the question of how to use a specific array in the 'for' loop, as per the script argument.